# jQuery mouseover mouseout issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some issue with a piece of code, i am using a sort of tooltip on links, but when a link has child elements in it, it blinks quick(when i hover over the child element(s)).

basic jQuery code(the part that shows the tip)(stripped down version, can not use a hover event!)

```
    $('.aaa').bind('mouseover mouseout',function(e) {
        if(e.type == 'mouseover'){
           $('.tip').show() 
        }else{
           $('.tip').hide() 
        } 
    });
```

this works

```
    <a href="#" class="aaa"></a>
```

this works not(good)

```
   <a href="#" class="aaa">
      <img src="images/icon.png"/>
      <span>text</span>
   </a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use mouseenter and mouseleave instead of mouseover mouseout.

Mouse over/out are triggered once for every child element.  Enter/leave are what you want/expect.  jQuery has normalized these across all browsers.

EDIT: here's a ref page: http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: +1, but I've even had issues with those so `hover()` would be better.  I wonder why he can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `hover()` method

```
var $tip = $('.tip');

$('.aaa').hover(
    function() {
        $tip.show();
    },
    function() {
        $tip.hide();
    }
);
```

Comment: The question specifically says that the `hover` event cannot be used.